# textarea 100% width in div bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to design the webpage and there is textarea under div element as below code.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="taskDescription" rows="2" class="form-control" id="txtDescription" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make textarea to take the parent elements width automatically, I tried using inherit width but that doesn't help.

How to accomplish this, please help me.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted actual code

Comment: Let me clarify I don't want to make any changes in bootstrap css, please post some other possible options.

Comment: Your code takes 100% even without modifying. What is the problem with that?

Comment: People started down-voting, they should wait at least my reply upon duplicate link, I did not find the solution that's why I have posted question over here, even tested below answers that working on fiddle but not working in my code.

Comment: I will setup fiddle and try to explain my problem there.

Answer (score 12):

Just use `.form-control` class, that's integrated in bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <textarea rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

It setup the 100% width of the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `width: 100%` will take full width of the parent.

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-12">
  <textarea rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I deleted the answer because I did not use inbuilt Bootstrap class but saw down votes on other answers too. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/mjh8jme7/ The textarea inherit the width of the div and it will not overflow.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <textarea rows="2"></textarea>
</div>

.col-md-12 textarea {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
     width: inherit;
}

.col-md-12 {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%` will take full width of the parent.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <textarea rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

Css File

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to edit bootstrap css.

Comment: Plz refer this http://jsfiddle.net/Z4CyF/7/